# Perform Segue Once AVAudioPlayer is finished

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I have an AVAudioPlayer and I want it so that once it is finished playing, it performs a segue. Here's a snippet of the code of what I tried. There is tons of more lines, the audio player is called audioPlayer.

```
import UIKit  
import AVFoundation  

class OnandOnViewController: UITableViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {  

override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  

}  

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {  
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: self)  
}  


}
```

I added the AVAudioPlayerDelegate and lines 11-13, but nothing happened when it ended. Have any ideas?

Comment: Did `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` get called?

Comment: @i_am_jorf No, I don't think it did, actually. Where is a good place to put it?

Comment: There is no audio player in your code!

Comment: @matt Yes there is, there is tons of other lines of code. It's called audioPlayer

Comment: He meant audio code that we can see. Anyway did you set the delegate for your `audioPlayer`?

Comment: Exactly. If you don't show us the relevant code, you force us to guess. That's silly. Do you want help or not? If you do, prove that there is an OnandOnViewController and that it is, in fact, the audio player's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        //perform segues
}
```